# How to do a slight left align in HTML with materializeCSS

Tags: html, materialize

This is a two part question. I am trying to emulate this mockup.

[image]

I am not quite sure how to do the slight left align of the text as well as adding a circular image in the gray circle area. Currently, my code in this area looks like this:

```html
<div class="index-banner color2">
    <div class="section">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col s12 center">
          <h5 class="header col s12 light">A modern responsive front-end framework based on Material Design</h5>
            <p class="left-align light">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam scelerisque id nunc nec volutpat. Etiam pellentesque tristique arcu, non consequat magna fermentum ac. Cras ut ultricies eros. Maecenas eros justo, ullamcorper a sapien id, viverra ultrices eros. Morbi sem neque, posuere et pretium eget, bibendum sollicitudin lacus. Aliquam eleifend sollicitudin diam, eu mattis nisl maximus sed. Nulla imperdiet semper molestie. Morbi massa odio, condimentum sed ipsum ac, gravida ultrices erat. Nullam eget dignissim mauris, non tristique erat. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae;</p>
          </div>
        <div class="row center">
          <a href="HackPrep.html" class="btn-large waves-effect waves-light green lighten-1" >HackPrep</a>
          <span class="divider2"/>
          <a href="Hackathons.html" class="btn-large waves-effect waves-light green lighten-1">Hackathons</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

It looks like this:

[image]

How do I make it look remotely close to the mockup? (ignoring the font color and size)

Answer (score 0):

Run below snippet in full page mode.

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.98.0/css/materialize.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="index-banner color2">
    <div class="section">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col l8 s12 center">
          <h5 class="header col s12 light">A modern responsive front-end framework based on Material Design</h5>
            <p class="left-align light ">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam scelerisque id nunc nec volutpat. Etiam pellentesque tristique arcu, non consequat magna fermentum ac. Cras ut ultricies eros. Maecenas eros justo, ullamcorper a s;</p>
          
        <div class="row center">
          <a href="HackPrep.html" class="btn-large waves-effect waves-light green lighten-1" >HackPrep</a>
          <span class="divider2"/>
          <a href="Hackathons.html" class="btn-large waves-effect waves-light green lighten-1">Hackathons</a>
        </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col l4 s12 center"><img src="https://dummyimage.com/200x200/000/fff" class="circle">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```